# How to group a vector into a list of vectors?

Tags: r, list, vector, grouping

I have some data which looks like this (fake data for example's sake):

```
dressId        color 
6              yellow 
9              red
10             green 
10             purple 
10             yellow 
12             purple 
12             red
```

where color is a factor vector. It is not guaranteed that all possible levels of the factor actually appear in the data (e.g. the color  "blue" could also be one of the levels).

I need a list of vectors which groups the available colors of each dress:

```
[[1]]
yellow  

[[2]] 
red    

[[3]] 
green purple yellow 

[[4]] 
purple red
```

Preserving the IDs of the dresses would be nice (e.g. a dataframe where this list is the second column and the IDs are the first), but not necessary.

I wrote a loop which goes through the dataframe row for row, and while the next ID is the same, it adds the color to a vector. (I am sure that the data is sorted by ID). When the ID in the first column changes, it adds the vector to a list:

```
result <- NULL 
while(blah blah) 
{
    some code which creates the vector called "colors" 
    result[[dressCounter]] <- colors 
    dressCounter <- dressCounter + 1
}
```

After wrestling with getting all the necessary counting variables correct, I found out to my dismay that it doesn't work. The first time, `colors` is

```
[1] yellow
Levels: green yellow purple red blue
```

and it gets coerced into an integer, so `result` becomes `2`.

In the second loop repetition, `colors` only contains red, and `result` becomes a simple integer vector, `[1] 2 4`.

In the third repetition, `colors` is a vector now,

```
[1] green  purple yellow
Levels: green yellow purple red blue
```

and I get

```
result[[3]] <- colors
```

> Error in result[[3]] <- colors :
>         more elements supplied than there are to replace

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to initialize `result` so it doesn't get converted into a numeric vector, but becomes a list of vectors?

Also, is there another way to do the whole thing than "roll my own"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`split.data.frame` is a good way to organize this; then extract the color component.

```
d <- data.frame(dressId=c(6,9,10,10,10,12,12),
               color=factor(c("yellow","red","green",
                              "purple","yellow",
                              "purple","red"),
                 levels=c("red","orange","yellow",
                          "green","blue","purple")))
```

I think the version you want is actually this:

```
ss <- split.data.frame(d,d$dressId)
```

You can get something more like the list you requested by extracting the color component:

```
lapply(ss,"[[","color")
```

Comment: +1 If it is just the list they want (unclear from the description) perhaps it is better to do that with `split` directly and skip the `lapply` step.

Comment: From the description, "I need a list of vectors which groups the available colors," maybe `split(d$color, d$dressId)` or `split(as.character(d$color), d$dressId)` would suffice.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to `split`, you should consider `aggregate`. Use `c` or `I` as the aggregation function to get your `list` column:

```
out <- aggregate(color ~ dressId, mydf, c)
out
#   dressId                 color
# 1       6                yellow
# 2       9                   red
# 3      10 green, purple, yellow
# 4      12           purple, red
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ dressId: int  6 9 10 12
#  $ color  :List of 4
#   ..$ 0: chr "yellow"
#   ..$ 1: chr "red"
#   ..$ 2: chr  "green" "purple" "yellow"
#   ..$ 3: chr  "purple" "red"
out$color
# $`0`
# [1] "yellow"
# 
# $`1`
# [1] "red"
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "green"  "purple" "yellow"
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "purple" "red"
```

---

***Note***: This works even if the "color" variable is a `factor`, as in Ben's sample data (I missed that point when I posted the answer above) but you need to use `I` as the aggregation function instead of `c`:

```
out <- aggregate(color ~ dressId, d, I)
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ dressId: num  6 9 10 12
#  $ color  :List of 4
#   ..$ 0: Factor w/ 6 levels "red","orange",..: 3
#   ..$ 1: Factor w/ 6 levels "red","orange",..: 1
#   ..$ 2: Factor w/ 6 levels "red","orange",..: 4 6 3
#   ..$ 3: Factor w/ 6 levels "red","orange",..: 6 1
out$color
# $`0`
# [1] yellow
# Levels: red orange yellow green blue purple
# 
# $`1`
# [1] red
# Levels: red orange yellow green blue purple
# 
# $`2`
# [1] green  purple yellow
# Levels: red orange yellow green blue purple
# 
# $`3`
# [1] purple red   
# Levels: red orange yellow green blue purple
```

Strangely, however, the default display shows the integer values:

```
out
#   dressId   color
# 1       6       3
# 2       9       1
# 3      10 4, 6, 3
# 4      12    6, 1
```

Comment: How to get strings instead of integer values?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your data frame is saved in a variable called `df`, then you can use simply `group_by` and `summarize` with `list` function of `dplyr` package like this

```
library('dplyr')

df %>%
  group_by(dressId) %>%
  summarize(colors = list(color))
```

Applied to your example:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~dressId, ~color,
         6, 'yellow',
         9, 'red',
        10, 'green',
        10, 'purple',
        10, 'yellow',
        12, 'purple',
        12, 'red'
)

df %>%
  group_by(dressId) %>%
  summarize(colors = list(color))

# dressId                colors
#       6                yellow
#       9                   red
#      10 green, purple, yellow
#      12           purple, red
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the answer should be a little different, you should use the following code to accomplish the requested behaviour

```
df %>%
group_by(dressId) %>%
summarize(colors = toString(unique(color)))
```

Comment: That will create a string, the question is asking for a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers do the job and I'm slightly late to the party, but some have used dplyr, and I always try to stay away from tidyverse if possible, and for this problem one can use the base R without tidyverse bloat. Some others have solved this through making a dataframe and that is not what the title says :)

let's create the vectors as OP didn't provide us the code (note that OP wants vector and not a dataframe although you can do this with a dataframe with a minor modification):

```r
dressId <- c(6, 9, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12)
color <- c("yellow", "red", "green", "purple", "yellow", "purple", "red")
```

Now let's get to the business and calculate what OP asked for:

> I need a list of vectors which groups the available colors of each dress:

```r
result <- split(x = color, f = dressId)

result
```

which will output:

> ```
> $`6`
> [1] "yellow"
>
> $`9`
> [1] "red"
>
> $`10`
> [1] "green"  "purple" "yellow"
>
> $`12`
> [1] "purple" "red"
> ```

This is very simple and straight forward. Now, **if** you have more than one pair, for instance if you have another "red" for the dressID of `12`, then you can pass the result of `split()` to `unique()`:

```r
result <- lapply(result, unique)
```

If you have the `color` as a factor, technically it should also work but it will make every item of the `result` a factor. to mitigate that, simply use `unfactor()` from `varhandle` package to convert your factor to a non-factor vector.