# Function to group elements of a vector/list

Tags: r, grouping

Suppose I have a vector such as

```
vec <- 0:10
```

and a function such as

```
f <- function (x) x %% 3
```

Is there a builtin function in R that will break this vector into groups based on the return value of `f` when applied to each element?  If not, what is the most straightforward way to implement this using built-ins?

The expected return value is

```
list(c(0,3,6,9), c(1,4,7,10), c(2,5,8))
```

For a more complicated example, take a vector of strings, and group together those which are anagrams (i.e. they consist of the same letters). In this case, `f` would take a string, lowercase it, and sort it.   On Unix systems there's a word list available:

```
words <- scan('/usr/share/dict/words', what=character, sep='\n')
```

I do not insist on using these particular data structures (vector, list), if they are not the most appropriate for this task in R.

Comment: There's `split`: `split(0:10, (0:10) %% 3)`

Comment: You'd need `vec <- 0:10` and then use `split(vec, f(vec))`. For breaking up strings as you mention there's `strsplit`. Like `strsplit(c("this is some string", "and another one"), split="")`.

Comment: Thank you.  Will you post an answer or is this question too simple to be kept and I better delete it?

Comment: It's likely a dupe. Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499679/how-to-group-a-vector-into-a-list-of-vectors?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` can separate a vector into lists (among other things) based on factors. See `?split` for more information. I became interested in grouping vector of words based on anagrams. So here's one solution for that

```
vec = c("stop", "pots", "leaves")
split(vec, sapply(vec, function(x)
    paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(tolower(gsub(" ", "", x)), ""))), collapse = "")))
#$aeelsv
#[1] "leaves"

#$opst
#[1] "stop" "pots"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr` and transform the input into a `data.frame`. From there, the code is easier to read:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(
   value = vec,
   stringsAsFactors = T
) %>%
mutate(
  result = f(value)
) %>%
group_by(result) %>%
summarize(
   list_result = list(value)
) %>%
.$list_result
```