# Split column into vectors by group R - independent of column order

Tags: r, list, vector

**Edit**
This question seems to be a duplicate of the question [How to group a vector into a list of vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499679/how-to-group-a-vector-into-a-list-of-vectors]), and the answer `split(df$b, df$id)` was suggested. First happy with the solution, I realized that the given answers do not fully address my question. In the below question, I would like to obtain a list in which the vector elements are assigned to the value of a third column (in my example `df$a`). This is important, as otherwise the *order* of `df$b` plays a role. I mean obviously I can arrange by `df$a` and then call `split()`, but maybe there is another way of doing that.

My sample df:

```
df <- data_frame(id = paste0('id',rep(1:2, each = 5)), a = rep(letters[1:5],2),b=c(1:5,5:1))
```

Df should be grouped by ID (in `df$id`). I would like to create a list of vectors for each group (id) element that contains the values of `df$b`. My approach

```
require(tidyr)
spread_df <- df %>%  spread(id,b) #makes new columns for each id

#loop over spread_df
for (i in 1:length(spread_df)) {
list_group_elements [i]<- list(spread_df[[i]])

#I want each vector to be identified by the identifier of column df$a
#therefore:

names(list_group_elements[[i]]) <- list_group_elements[[1]]
}
```

This results in :

```
list_group_elements
[[1]]
 a   b   c   d   e 
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" 

[[2]]
a b c d e 
1 2 3 4 5 

[[3]]
a b c d e 
5 4 3 2 1
```

I don't need the first element of the list, but the rest is basically what I need. I have the peculiar impression that my approach is somewhat not ideal and if someone has an idea to improve this, (e.g., with dplyr?) this would be highly appreciated. Why do I want this: I made a function that uses vectors as arguments and I would like to run this function over certain columns from dataframes - but only using the grouped values as arguments and not the entire column.

Comment: `split(df$b, df$id)`

Comment: @Henrik, Thanks for pointing this out and especially for helping me to understand the cumbersome question and answer you are pointing to. I had actually seen this question and as it was asked in a for me not clear way, I thought it was not was I was looking for. But you are of course absolutely right and thanks for digging out the answer to the question which is hidden within a comment.

Comment: @Henrik moreover, I was thinking if you could kindly offer your solution as an answer, I could accept that and other inexperienced users as me could find this fantastic answer more easily, as it would not be tugged away in a comment..

Comment: @Henrik, again, after some consideration - I believe all the given answers are not entirely what I wanted. I have edited my question and hope that it made clearer what I need.

Comment: You may make `df$b` a named vector before splitting: `split(setNames(df$b, df$a), df$id)`.

Comment: simple and brilliant. Thanks again, @Henrik. Could you maybe make your split approach an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make `df$b` a named vector using `setNames`, and then `split` it into a list:

```
split(setNames(df$b, df$a), df$id)
# $id1
# a b c d e 
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 
# $id2
# a b c d e 
# 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
lapply(levels(df$id), function(L) df$b[df$id == L])
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: I thought of lapply, but did not think of creating this nice function. Thanks!! That answers my question. Fantastic. (I can accept your answer only in a few minutes... )

Comment: although I admit- I don't really understand this function... lol. Need to figure this one out.

Comment: Why lapply? `split(df$b,df$id)`

Comment: Yes, @Henrik had suggested this and this is by far the most elegant solution.

Comment: @G5W sorry, I have un-accepted your answer because I realized after Henrik's comment that the given answers do not fully address my question - not your bad but my question was not precisely asked. I have now edited my question and I hope that it made this somewhat clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `by`, object-oriented wrapper of `tapply`, designed to split dataframe by factor(s):

```
by(df, df$id, FUN=function(i) i$b)
```

Comment: interesting!! thanks. Unfortunately, @G5W was faster with the answer, but I really like the short code.